# ASP.Net How to enforce the HTTP get URL format?

Tags: asp.net, validation, http-get

[Sorry about a messy question. I believe I am targeting .Net 2.0 (for now)]

Hi, I am an ASP.NET noob. For starters I am building a page that parses a URL string and populates a table in a database. I want that string to be strictly of the form:

```
http://<server>:<port>/PageName.aspx?A=1&B=2&C=3&D=4&E=5
```

The order of the arguments does not matter, I just do not want any of them missing, or any extras. Here is what I tried (yes, it is ugly; I just want to get it to work first):

```
#if (DEBUG)
        // Maps parameter names to their human readable names.
        // Used for error checking.
        private static Dictionary<string, string> paramNameToDisplayName = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "A", "a"},
            { "B", "b"},
            { "C", "c"},
            { "D", "d"},
            { "E", "e"},
            { "F", "f"},
       };


        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private void validateRequestParameters(HttpRequest request)
        {
            bool endResponse = false;
            // Use foreach var
            foreach (string expectedParameterName in paramNameToDisplayName.Keys)
            {
                if (request[expectedParameterName] == null)
                {
                    Response.Write(String.Format("No parameter \"{0}\", aka {1} was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.",
                        expectedParameterName, paramNameToDisplayName[expectedParameterName]));
                    endResponse = true;
                }
            }
            // Use foreach var
            foreach (string actualParameterName in request.Params)
            {
                if (!paramNameToDisplayName.ContainsKey(actualParameterName))
                {
                    Response.Write(String.Format("The parameter \"{0}\", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.",
                        actualParameterName));
                    endResponse = true;
                }
            }
            if (endResponse)
            {
                Response.End();
            }
        }
#endif
```

and it works ok, except that it complains about all sorts of other stuff:

http://localhost:1796/AddStatusUpdate.aspx?X=0

---

No parameter "A", aka a was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.No parameter "B", aka b was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.No parameter "C", aka c was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.No parameter "D", aka d was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.No parameter "E", aka e was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.No parameter "F", aka f was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "X", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "ASP.NET_SessionId", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "ALL_HTTP", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "ALL_RAW", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "APPL_MD_PATH", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "AUTH_TYPE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "AUTH_USER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "AUTH_PASSWORD", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "LOGON_USER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "REMOTE_USER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_COOKIE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_FLAGS", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_ISSUER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_KEYSIZE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_SERIALNUMBER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_SERVER_ISSUER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CERT_SUBJECT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CONTENT_LENGTH", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "CONTENT_TYPE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "GATEWAY_INTERFACE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTPS", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTPS_KEYSIZE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "INSTANCE_ID", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "INSTANCE_META_PATH", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "LOCAL_ADDR", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "PATH_INFO", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "PATH_TRANSLATED", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "QUERY_STRING", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "REMOTE_ADDR", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "REMOTE_HOST", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "REMOTE_PORT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "REQUEST_METHOD", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SCRIPT_NAME", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SERVER_NAME", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SERVER_PORT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SERVER_PORT_SECURE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SERVER_PROTOCOL", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "SERVER_SOFTWARE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "URL", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_CONNECTION", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_ACCEPT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_COOKIE", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_HOST", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.The parameter "HTTP_USER_AGENT", was passed to the configuration generator, but it was not expected. Check your URL string / cookie.Thread was being aborted.

---

Is there some way for me to separate the implicit and the explicit parameters, or is it not doable? Should I even bother? Perhaps the philosophy of get is to just throw away that what is not needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dictionary should have a string key, your code doesn't have "" around the keys:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> paramNameToDisplayName = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "A", "a"},
    { "B", "b"},
    { "C", "c"},
    { "D", "d"},
    { "E", "e"},
    { "F", "f"},
```

};

For the rest of the errors, try using this, your code was looking for all posted params, not just the querystring params (request.QueryString.AllKeys):

```
if (!request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains<string>(expectedParameterName))
                {
                    Response.Write(String.Format("No parameter \"{0}\", aka {1} was passed to the configuration generator. Check your URL string / cookie.", expectedParameterName, paramNameToDisplayName[expectedParameterName]));
                    endResponse = true;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that I need generics and Linq for this to work.

Comment: QUESTION: how do I get Contains<string> to work with case-insensitive comparer? I saw the option for the second parameter; I just do not know which generic class implements that interface and does what I want. thanks!

Comment: Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains<string>(expectedParameterName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 1):

As drousseau mentions, you'll need to use the `QueryString` collection instead of `Params`. `Params` includes ALL data passed on the request, which means cookies, form POST data, querystring parameters and servervariables.

It looks like you're checking the cookies as well, so you'll either need to do a separate check through that collection, or merge the two by using something like this:

```
        var both = (
            from key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys
            select new { Key = key, Value = Request.QueryString[key] }).Union(
            from key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys
            select new { Key = key, Value = Request.Cookies[key].Value }).ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

It's also worth noting that you're also going to be getting a cookie dropped by ASP.NET session state. You can either code around it by explicitly ignoring cookies named "ASP.NET_SessionId" (easiest), or just turn off session state in web.config - you'll need to clear your cookies though.

**EDIT:** just saw the bit about targeting 2.0, which means that nice little LINQ statement is out of the question. It would probably be easiest to just check each of the collections (QueryString and Cookies) separately.

**EDIT PART DEUX:**
Here's a non-LINQ alternative to using a single lookup:

```
        NameValueCollection both = new NameValueCollection(Request.QueryString);
        foreach (String key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            if (key != "ASP.NET_SessionId") both.Add(key, Request.Cookies[key].Value);
        }
```

Using a hard-coded string like that is ugly, but hey, it should work.

I'd also like to point out that if you used ASP.NET MVC or even just System.Web.Routing (both of which unfortunately require .NET 3.5), you wouldn't have to do ANY of this, since the routing framework does it all for you - and you'd get typed parameters to boot!

Comment: Daniel, I might be able to upgrade to 3.5 or 4.0, BUT I am just diving into ASP.Net and there is limited time. In the LINQ example - once I have both, what do I do with it? Also, how exactly does a cookie affect me. I copied part of the error message from elsewhere but do not understand how a cookie comes into a play here. Thanks again!

Comment: Use the "both" dictionary to iterate on and do your checks instead of Request.Params.

I included the cookies because they're mentioned in your Response.Write call. ASP.NET uses something called session state (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) to persist data about a user's session between requests. The default way it keeps track of it is by using a cookie, which is set automatically. So, if you're checking for cookies, the session state cookie is going to show up automatically, which means you need to account for it if you're only expecting specified values to be set.